# Dual hard drive Windows 7 system, modified the registry to get programs to install on second drive, now IE doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I have a dual hard drive Windows 7 system, Windows is installed on an SSD (C:) and I modified the registry to try to force programs to install on second HDD drive (another letter). The registry edits are pretty simple, just a few keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion to change the drive letter. For the most part the system is very fast and works great, but IE doesn't work anymore. With IE10, it opens for a flash with a white window then closes. I tried installed IE11 which opens a white window for a few seconds, doesn't respond, then crashes.

I've tried all the solutions I could find. This includes resetting the IE settings, "uninstalling" and re-installing IE, which is just turning it on and off in "Turn Windows Features on or off", copying the Program Files\Internet Explorer files onto both/either drives, changing the registry keys back to use C:, lots of rebooting, and safe mode. Nothing has worked. I don't see errors in the event viewer, but I might not know what to look for.

Any ideas on how to get IE running?

I don't need IE for daily browsing, I just need it for cross-browser testing on sites I build and on the rare occasion a page only works in IE. I don't really want to use a virtual machine, but would be ok with something standalone like tredosoft's, but I'm not aware of something like that for current versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only use it rarely :)

Go here and try those if you haven't already: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318378

Also maybe try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737

You seem to have done most other things so far.

In terms of your configuration, I don't see why you would need to create this sort of set up. If you install Windows on the SSD, each subsequent program you install can be targeted at another HD during installation without any registry tweaks.

I would suggest re-installing and doing a cleaner setup. Some programs should be installed on the SSD also to take full advantage of it.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried both of those links already, but they didn't work. The installation was normal, I made the registry changes after I installed, so I'm not sure why reinstalling would fix it, but next time I have 5-6 hours to spare, I may try that... I do install programs to the SSD sometimes, my setup allows that, but I've seen very little difference there

Comment: You have modified your installation in some way due to the registry changes you made after the installation. Reinstalling would reset those changes and leave you with a functioning IE. Even so, I still do not understand why you would go such an unorthodox route and not simple change the install directory of each program you are installing to be where you want it (SSD or HD) - (C or D).

Comment: Ok. I did it because some programs don't ask you where to install, and this usually forces them to go to the alternative drive. It's a pretty simple change with few side effects - although clearly it has screwed up IE.